# Are there quantum states of closed systems which are superpositions of different energy levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, superposition

As far as I can see superpositions are legitimate solutions of the time dependent equation for a closed quantum system.

By closed system I mean a system that does not exchange energy with an external system.

I posed this question because I have seen a number of posts on physics sites where it is claimed that the only allowed states for isolated systems are eigenstates of energy.

Comment: Double slit experiment?

Comment: The double well potential is a popular example where the two lowest energy eigenstates can be added/subtracted to make states where a particle is localised in the left/right well. Since these states are not energy eigenstates they will eventually lead to tunnelling. But they are totally valid states.

Comment: How about qubit whose Hamiltonian is:

Comment: How about qubit whose Hamiltonian is: diagE,E, antidiag F,F.  Its eigenstates are (1,1) and (1,-1) with eigenvalues E+F and E-F.  A superposition starting in (1,0) precesses. It's isolated. Any comments?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I believe so. For example in the "particle in a box" model system, which is a simple very extensively discussed model closed system for teaching, all the "interesting" states, ie. all the states where there is motion of the particle in the classically understood sense, are superpositions. So more than superpositions being allowed, they are required, to explore most of the interesting aspects of the system. This is true for quantum systems in general.